# Automatting shell scripts

Tags: shell

I am trying to automate a set of commands which are written into a file. I need to use 'crontab' here and must specify the time at which the file need to run. But I am not exactly sure on how to do it.
FileName: UAMainFile

I googled, trying to find a way on how to specialize crontab. But I could not understand them. Finally I am here..

I need the file UAMainFile to run on everyday morning 8. Can some one help in this?
FYI - I logged into one of my peer's linux machine using putty and trying to schedule this file.

Comment: have you read this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)? This gives you clear understanding on how to set up crontab.

Comment: I have read.  I have created this cronjob. 5 * * * * /tmp/UAMmainfile  I want the file UAMainFile to run on every five minute. Is this correct??

Answer (score 2):

Run `crontab -e`

Paste this cheat sheet at the above your program entries for reference:

```
# +------------ minute (0 - 59)
# | +---------- hour (0 - 23)
# | | +-------- day of month (1 - 31)
# | | | +------ month (1 - 12)
# | | | | +---- day of week (0 - 6, 0 = Sunday)
# | | | | | |-- command to run...
#
# 5 0 * * * <some command to run at 0:05 of every day of every month
```

See `man 5 crontab` for more info on the proper configuration of crontab entries.

Answer (score 0):

Run `crontab -e`

> ## +------------ minute (0 - 59)
>
> ## | +---------- hour (0 - 23)
>
> ## | | +-------- day of month (1 - 31)
>
> ## | | | +------ month (1 - 12)
>
> ## | | | | +---- day of week (0 - 6, 0 = Sunday)
>
> ## | | | | | |-- command to run...
>
> ## 0 8 * * * (some command to run at 8:00 of every day of every month)

the above entry in crontab will run the given command at 8:00 every day